# C++ - Active threads executing specific tasks

Tags: c++, multithreading

A process is initialized and it creates some threads. I need to make a program that assigns tasks to the threads, and whenever one or some of them finish, possibly assign them other tasks if needed.

I have a class which has the number of threads (configured via command line), and essentially the tasks will be executed via `exec()` functions family. I've defined an array of `pthreads`, but not sure if I need to create them immediately or... I don't know. This is the header for the class I'm using:

```
class Pcp{
  private:
    int id;
    int nThreads;
    pthread_t thrs[];
    Message* m;
  public:
    Pcp(int id, int nthreads);
    ~Pcp();
    void assignTask(int thread, Task* t);
    void verifyThreadsState(); //check if anyone has finished
```

There is a `struct Message` which has an array of `Tasks` to execute. This is the struct of `Tasks`:

```
struct Task{
    bool assigned;
    char taskToExec[MAX_TEXT_AREA];
    unsigned short threadId;
};
```

How can I build the `assignTask` and `verifyThreadsState` functions for this?

Comment: Lookup about _thread pool_ implementations please.

Comment: Since you have C++ tag in your question I strongly recommend to switch to `std::thread`.

Comment: @ixSci `std::thread` is only available since C++11.

Comment: @Sebastian What year is it?

Comment: @AlanStokes 2016 as far as I can tell. Yet we got full 11 support for msvc just half a year ago with expression SFINAE still missing. Many C++11 features where still lacking in msvc13. Support for C++14, which is basically C++11.5, is still lacking many features in msvc15 as well. So to assume that C++ == C++11 nowadays is simply wrong. It takes a long while for compilers to implement all features and even more time for people to adapt.